# How to save changes permanently in inspect element?

Tags: python, html, django

I have a problem. I am working in Django and I downloaded template and made changes in `main.css` but it is not working. I then made changes in inspect element in browser. But I don't know how to save it permanently.

In Django I wrote it as `{{form}}` in HTML page but the changes in `main.css` is not working.

How to deal with that?

Comment: you can write a override.css and include that at last of all css imports in html

Comment: Will you please explain? I didn't understand.

Comment: first of all, when you updated the main.css, did you restart the server and clear cache to check if its reflecting properly? Second, there should bunch of css imports in template like `<link src=...>`, after the last import, your should import your `override.css`(or any name.css) file, then the changes inside `override.css` will override the other css attributes.